can not upload new update of my app on xcode 16
Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' contains bitcode. (ID: 5c806ec7-2b8f-4ba7-a798-7a465a9aec8c)
Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit' contains bitcode. (ID: 793d6c5b-96d8-4870-a21a-f8e0c5321f4e)
Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics' contains bitcode. (ID: ef59c9a9-027d-438b-b49b-e93021e52c36)
Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit' contains bitcode. (ID: 56b3fd70-9d6c-433f-8687-fc4f02398072)
received this error after archive app and upload it to apple

Xcode 16 cannot upload archive contains bitcode。Try thisremove or leave the bitcode segment in a Mach-O file
